# Text doesn't fit in the box when editing

Tags: bug, android-app

When you are editing a post on the Android app, the text doesn't really fit in the box. It simply overflows like the box is just a background image and also there's a small empty space at the bottom of the screen for some reason.

Take a look at this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Hmm, I'm unable to reproduce, might help if you add your Android version (and possibly phone model).

Comment: @TimStone I'm using Samsung Galaxy Note 4 on Android 4.4.4.